# How do I isolate the name property of a model being included in my controller for the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two models `DiscountTypes` and `Discounts`. In my view I can display the `DiscountType.Name` property of my `Discounts`in my foreach loop by adding the following to my controller:

```
var eDiscounts = db.EDiscounts.Include(e => e.DiscountTypes);
```

and in my view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DiscountTypes.Name)
```

This works fine, however, I would like to get the actual string being printed out in order to change the values out in a switch statement(for example):

```
case "Apparel and Accessories":
DiscountTypes.Name = "foo";
break;
```

I have tried this:

```
var DTDiscounts = db.EDiscounts.Include(e => e.DiscountTypes);
var DTD = DTDiscounts.ToList();
var myDis = (from e in DTD select e.DiscountTypes.Name).ToList();
ViewBag.DType = myDis;
```

Which simply prints out **System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]**

I have also tried using `.First()`but it just gives me the first type in the iteration repeated for all rows. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. _I would like to get the actual string being printed out in order to change the values out in a switch statement_ -- which string, which value? Where's the switch statement? _prints out System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]_ Where's the code that produces this?

Comment: @Jasen The switch statement is irrelevant. I am simply asking how to isolate the `DiscountType.Name` string

Comment: You have a list of strings so you will have to loop over them in order to sprint them each.  Otherwise the generic `.ToString()` method just prints the object type rather than the object's information.